# Pop every row with nan column to different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where a certain column will often contain 'nan'. I want to take every row that this occurs in and pop it to a different df, is this possible?

EX:

```
index    Make    Color
  1      Ford     Red
  2      Ford     nan
  3      Chevy    Blue
```

The TWO resulting df's would look like so:

```
index    Make    Color
  1      Ford     Red
  2      Chevy    Blue

index    Make    Color
  1      Ford     nan
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `groupby` and unpack the results to variables.

```
(_,df_1), (_,df_2) = df.groupby(df.Color.isna())
```

where `df_1` has no nulls, `df_2` has the nulls.

Comment: Nice... I've never thought of using groupby with tuple assignments like this before.  Awesome.  +1

Comment: Actually, the question is "where a `certain` column will often contain 'nan'", not only `Color`.

Comment: @yahocho exactly, there is a *specific column* (i.e. a certain column) that often contain `Nan`s. Just replace `Color` by this actual column :}

Comment: By doing `df.isna().any` you are splitting based on all columns, which is not what OP suggested. Of course, you can still use groupby on `df.isna().any(1)` and my answer still works. But not what OP suggested

Answer (score 4):

just use boolean indexing with `isna` and `any`:

```
df_nan = df[df.isna().any(1)]
df_other = df[~df.isna().any(1)]
```